# JQuery Hide Element not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have an `<ul>` with plenty of `<li>`'s under it. Each of these `<li>`'s has a hidden `<div class=dbox">` within. The structure/hierarchy for the `<li>`'s and their content is:

--> li 
---->visible content (h3, img, p, etc.) 
---->hidden div.dbox 
-------> div.photos 
-------> div.specs

When clicking the `<li>`'s image (always visible), `<div class="dbox">` is then given display=block. So far so good. I then searched the web to get the .dbox to close whenever clicking outside it. I got this to work:

```
var mouse_is_inside = false;

    $('.dbox').hover(function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
        if(! mouse_is_inside) $('.dbox').hide();
    });
```

Clicking outside .dbox now makes it close. So far so good. Next step was to add a 'close this window button for less tech-savy users, so, within the `<div class="specs">`, I added one last element, `<span class="close">`  then gave it this jquery code:

```
$('span.close').click(function() {

        $(this).parent().parent().hide();

    });
```

Which did not work. I tested with parents('.dbox') and it didn't work either. Funny enough, it is only when I target .dbox that hide doesn't work. If I do something like:

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```

which would close the containing div, `<div class="specs">`, it works and effectively closes `<div class="specs">`

I then thought that there was some sort of conflict with the 'click outside' code so I removed it and the bug remained...which leads me here to ask you knowledge-able fellows about this dilemma.

Thanks in advance
G.Campos

Comment: I got it to work: $(this).parents('.dbox').hide(1);

It is only when hide() is empty that nothing happens. Adding 1 or whatever number does the trick. Why can't it be 0 though?

Comment: It would help if you put up an example on http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Sotkra: Can you confirm that the "dbox" `div` is shown when the `li` _image_ is clicked and not when the `li` itself it clicked?

Comment: $('span.close').click(function(e) {e.target.parentElement.style.display='none';}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work: `$(this).parents('.dbox').hide(1);`
It is only when hide() is empty that nothing happens. Adding 1 or whatever number does the trick. Why can't it be 0 though?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is you can set `mouse_is_inside=false;` in `onMouseLeave` event handler.

Another solution is to wire your event handlers like this:

```
$('.dbox').click(function(e) {
  // do stuff
  // ...

  // this will prevent the event from bubbling upto body's eventhandler
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').click(function(e) {
  $('.dbox').hide();
});
```

Also, this should close the parent dbox div:

```
$('.dbox span.close').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.dbox').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) instead of your trick with `mouse_inside`.

Moreover, you can use the [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) with a selector inside instead of your `parent().parent()`.

Max

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide(); // for button
```